# text and file utility in windows

Tags: text

I need to do things like: taking the first x lines of text file and save it into another text file,  what kind of text utilities can I use in windows?

Comment: By programming, command or manually? notepad.exe?

Comment: by command or manually like linux shells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a decent text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

If you aren't afraid of using the command line, I'd suggest taking a look at [Gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), which is a port of many useful *nix utilities for Windows.

It contains heavyweight such as [Sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [Awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk), [Grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) etc., which are more than suited for any kind of text surgery.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to write a batchfiles that extracts the first `10` lines of file `myInputFile.txt` to `myOutputFile.txt`  use

```
  head.exe --lines=10 myInputFile.txt > myOutputFile.txt
```

head.exe is one of severeal [GnuUtilities for MsWindows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).